# WordPress: Disable add custom field

Tags: wordpress, field

I allow a guest to post on my WordPress site. I disabled some fields, but I let the user select only one field.

Cool, but he can edit this field. 
Example: `Field: name`.
After I added it, he can rename the field to `name2`.

So, how do I can a disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `readonly` attribute,

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?php echo $name ?>" readonly="readonly">
```